# people who came to my server, role for people whose account is not secure

Tags: javascript

as you can see from the subject of the title, I wrote a code, but I can not pass the code correctly, so the role of 'jail' in the safe people gives

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
    let user = client.users.get(member.id);
require("moment-duration-format");
const kurulus = new Date().getTime() - user.createdAt.getTime();  
var control;
if (kurulus < 1296000000) control = `This Account Is Not Reliable `
  moment.locale("tr");
     
  var rol2 = member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "︲Cezalı üye");
    
  member.addRole(rol2);
      client.channels.get("role id").send(` \`${member.user.tag}\` Because the account for the named user has just been established \`${rol2.name}\` Named Was Given The Role.`);
  
});
```

thank you for your help I have started coding a new.

Comment: hotfix:  var rol2 = member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "role name");

Comment: Welcome to SO. In reading your question it is not clear what the specific problem is, what works and what doesn't and the expected behavior is of this code. Take a few minutes to thorughly read [ask] then edit the question with more specific details

Comment: Not quite clear what the question is.